# Applying a matching function for string and substring with missing values on a python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have programmed the following functionality:

The function returns True, when the two strings match sequentially except for a "*" value and false when they differ by at least 1 character.

```
def matching(row1, row2):
    string = row1['number']
    sub_string = row2['number']
    flag = True
    i=0
    if len(string) == len(sub_string):
        while i < len(string) and flag==True:
            if string[i] != "*" and sub_string[i] != "*":
                if string[i] != sub_string[i]:
                    flag = False
            i+=1
    else:
        flag = False
    
    return flag
```

Assuming I have a dataframe with the column 'number'. I want to apply this function to a dataframe in order to obtain the following format:

```
| number | unique_id |
| ------ | --------- |
| 178*A8 |     0     |
| 13**B4 |     1     |
| 17***8 |     0     |
| 82819B |     2     |
| 13**B4 |     1     |
```

I managed to write the unique_id with the following code, but it only works when the numbers match. I would like to perform the same functionality but using the function in the code first.

```
df['unique_id'] = pd.factorize(df['number'])[0]

| number | unique_id |
| ------ | --------- |
| 178*A8 |     0     |
| 13**B4 |     1     |
| 17***8 |     2     |
| 82819B |     3     |
| 13**B4 |     1     |
```

**Edited**: We will assume that matching will be done on a first-come, first-served basis. If the first value is 123*, all numbers matching('123*',X) == True will be assigned the same id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This corresponds to a deduplication or [record linkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_linkage) problem.

There are various ways to compare records (numbers in your case), but the main issue is almost always about [the double loop](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/54570/64377): in the general problem, every possible pair of records must be compared.
In case there are too many numbers for the double loop, you could implement the *blocking* technique [described here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/68413/64377).

Your design may have an additional issue: your matching method is not transitive, i.e. you can have cases where $a$ matches $b$, $b$ matches $c$ but $a$ doesn't $c$. Apparently you plan to solve this by picking the first match. This might not be optimal for matching a maximum of numbers.

I'm not expert at all with pandas but I doubt that there would be any predefined function which does what you need. `factorize` relies on strict equality, it's much simpler because it can collect all the unique values in one pass.